# Cannot import socketio (python-socketio) in Python2.7

Tags: python-2.7, import

Getting this error when trying to import socketio in python 2:

```
root@udacity:~/Desktop/CarND-Capstone-master/ros# python
Python 2.7.12 (default, Nov 19 2016, 06:48:10) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import socketio
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/socketio/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .client import Client
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/socketio/client.py", line 6, in <module>
    import engineio
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/engineio/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .client import Client
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/engineio/client.py", line 302
    'Unexpected response from server') from None
                                          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Tried reinstalling/installing socketio and engineio, but can't seem to get it to work. I should mention that I'm running in an Ubuntu VM.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer, as shown above, it was an engineio fault. Installing it before socketio in my requirements file worked. Particularly I'm using python-socketio==4.4.0, and python-engineio==3.11.2

```
python-engineio==3.11.2
python-socketio==4.4.0
```

Reference:

https://github.com/udacity/CarND-Capstone/issues/342